# VB ASP.NET - Add code to a control that is created by code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm using VB ASP.NET and would like to know how to add code to a control that is created by code behind?

For example in my Main.aspx.vb file I have the following code:

```
    Connection.Open()
        spRetrieveAlbums.ExecuteNonQuery()
        ReturnValue = spRetrieveAlbums.Parameters("@ReturnValue").Value
    Connection.Close()

    For I = 1 To ReturnValue
        Dim myAlbum = New ImageButton
        myAlbum.Visible = True
        myAlbum.Width = 150
        myAlbum.Height = 150
        myAlbum.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid
        myAlbum.BorderColor = Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke
        myAlbum.BorderWidth = 1
        AlbumsPanel.Controls.Add(myAlbum)
    Next I
```

ReturnValue stores the number of albums a person has (Using SQL Server stored procedure @@ROWCOUNT) and displays the same amount of ImageButtons within the 'AlbumsPanel' Panel on the web page.

I would like to use response.redirect("Albums.aspx") on a click event on any of the ImageButtons but not sure how I can achieve this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have created dynamically and you can use a delegate for min.VB10 and like that,

```
AddHandler myAlbum.Click, _
    Sub(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        //To Do for Response 
    End Sub
```

Comment: That works perfectly fine thank you :) Do you know if there's a way to identify which 1 the user clicked on? I have a SQL Server database with a table named Albums with the following columns [AlbumId, Id, AlbumName, NumOfPics, DateCreated, IsActive]. I was thinking of creating a stored procedure to retrieve the AlbumId's for each 1 and then naming each ImageButton using the MyAlbum.Id = 'AlbumId here' and then some how passing that value through to the MyAlbum.Click event

Comment: during creation of myAlbum, you desired can set to CommandArgument|CommandName values then get the values at the code side (sender as ImagageButton).CommandArgument etc.